# Unknown Option: -protocol error while using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I get the below exception while trying to execute testng.xml using chromedriver

```
Exception in thread "main" com.beust.jcommander.ParameterException: Unknown option: -protocol
```

I have chromedriver.exe in my local and works fine for non-testng tests. Has someone faced a similar issue.

Comment: You should post complete questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Update the question with your code trials and `testng.xml`

Answer (score 0):

This is nowhere related to the Chromedriver. It is the issue with the parameter named protocol` that you are not passing to the test method through the testng.xml file. For ex.

```
@Parameter("protocol")
@Test
void sampleTest(String protocol){
//your code
}
```

Expected testng.xml file

```
<suite name="Sample Suite">
 <test name="Sample Test">
   <parameter name="protocol" value="expectedvalue">
 </test> <!-- test -->
</suite>
```

Some time to avoid this situation, we use `@Optional` attribute

```
@Parameter("protocol")
@Test
void sampleTest(@Optional("http")String protocol){
//your code
}
```